# AWS SNS Adding Android Platform Endpoints Automatically

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-sns, android-push-notification

All I need is a way to send push notifications to all users on the android app, I task which I thought wouldn't be difficult but here we are.

So I've set up the firebase side, and I have created the platform application on AWS SNS and manually added tokens to test if the notification sends, all of that is successful. I now need a way of adding the tokens automatically to the platform application - for example when the user first installs the app, I can't find any tutorials somehow, I've looked at the docs on AWS but they seem to be very vague and don't really give a detailed answer or example that I can follow.

As far as I am aware this is possible, just no clear answer onto how.

I am using Android Studio developing in Java.

My full plan is to use Lambda functions, when they are triggered, to send the push notification to all users- my plan is to use boto3.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify that 'Automatically' add to platform application?

Answer (score 0):

A typical Amazon SNS integration for push notifications usually looks like this:

Firstly, create two APIs in API Gateway. Call them `RegisterEndpoint` and `UnregisterEndpoint`. These APIs should be implemented by AWS Lambda functions. The lambdas will call SNS's register/unregister APIs, and they will *also* add/remove information about the endpoint to/from a DynamoDB table.

Your backend code can then query your Dynamo table to look for available endpoints, when you want to send out push notifications. Design the table so that you can query by some property your backend has available (user's phone number, perhaps.)

In your mobile application, call your new `RegisterEndpoint` API when your user signs in, and call `UnregisterEndpoint` when they sign out.